# Create a virtual host with port forwarding in EasyPHP

Tags: apache, virtualhost, easyphp

I made an application built with EasyPhp on a Windows Server 2012.
This app listens on port 8000 and is reacheable by the URL `http://localhost:8000/myapp`
I want to make an alias in order to access to my app with something like `http://myapp.lan`
I know I have to create a new virtual host. I set it with :

```
  <VirtualHost *:8000>
  DocumentRoot "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds- 
 www\myapp
  ServerName myapp.lan
  </VirtualHost>
```

But it does not work..
I tried to modifiy the hosts file to set `127.0.0.1 myapp.lan`. But when I go to http://myapp.lan I can't access, being redirected to the default IIS page (port 80) of my Windows Server.

Could you help me ?
Thanks you !

Comment: This virtual host listens for connections coming in on port 8000 only. You can define server aliases in there all you want, it still has no influence on how your server handles requests on a totally different port …

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how could I do to define an alias like **http://myapp.lan** without the port ?

Comment: By using the _default_ ports - which would be 80 for HTTP, and 443 for HTTPS.